# Integrating $\sec\theta\tan^2\theta d\,\theta$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

I'm stuck in this problem. I can not integrate $\int \sec\theta\tan^2\theta \,d\theta$.
Can anyone help me.

Comment: WolframAlpha shows me a very complicated solution [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sec%28x%29tan%5E2%28x%29+)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
$$
\begin{align}
\int\sec(\theta)\tan^2(\theta)\,\mathrm{d}\theta
&=\int\frac{\sin^2(\theta)}{\cos^4(\theta)}\,\mathrm{d}\sin(\theta)\\
&=\int\frac{u^2}{(1-u^2)^2}\,\mathrm{d}u
\end{align}
$$
Now use partial fractions:
$$
\frac{u^2}{(1-u^2)^2}=\frac14\left[\frac1{(1-u)^2}-\frac1{1-u}+\frac1{(1+u)^2}-\frac1{1+u}\right]
$$

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, found a mistake on my previous post. Here is my new attempt. The integral is 
$\int (\sec^3 \theta - \sec \theta ) \ d\theta$. You can use integration by parts for $\int \sec ^3 \theta \ d\theta $ as in [this wiki link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_secant_cubed). 
And $\int \sec \theta\ d\theta = \ln |\sec \theta + \tan \theta|$.

Comment: why downvote? did I do anything wrong?